# Python & HTML: Make user login to use website

Tags: python, html, plone

I'm creating a website with a database search functionality, but I want to make the user login or create a account first to use the search functionality. How do I do this? And what is the easiest way to carry the login session forward. I.E. the user only has to login once to do many searches.

Comment: 2 downvotes with no comment/explanation?!  Sure, the question's a bit broad (and no hint of what was already tried/examined), but it turned out to be exactly my question, too: +1.  If you're going to ding someone's question, at least comment about how they can make it better.  That's how we learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Web Frameworks for Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks), and select one of the listed
**Popular Full-Stack Frameworks** (Django, TurboGears, ...).
Each framework provides its own session support.

SO discussions, for example [choosing-a-web-application-framework-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023111/choosing-a-web-application-framework-in-python),
can help you choose one that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache as your web server you can use the built-in Htaccess  command line tools for user management:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess

Htaccess is built-in to Apache and lets you manage users for PHP pages, CGI's (including Python), HTML pages, and others.

Here's a few example use-cases:

1. Initial setup:

   a. copy 3 .ht* files (.htpasswords, .htgroups, .htaccess) into your document root  (find templates of these files on the web).

   b. add "AllowOverride Authconfig" into your apache conf file
2. Create new user ('root') when .htpasswords file does not exist:

   `$ htpasswd  -c .htpasswords root`
3. add a user named 'root':

   `$ htpasswd /Users/username/Sites/.htpasswords root`
4. change password of user 'root':

   `$ htpasswd /Users/username/Sites/.htpasswords root`

In PHP you can see who logged in via htaccess and get their password with:

`$pass =  $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']; // from htaccess`

Htaccess is not super user-friendly, so feel free to update/improve my workflow

Comment: While technically this works, I don't think it scales the way the OP intends.  I read the question to mean setting up of a site where 1000s (millions?) of users press the "create account" button, and it has all that "forgot/reset password" stuff, etc.  Maybe I misread, but your answer seems to require sysop intervention for each new user.